# IIF-Else statement Never Reachs Else Condition

Tags: vba, if-statement, ssrs-2008

Im using this custom Code in SQL Reporting Services.  The problem is it NEVER reachs the false condition. If the condition is NOT true, the function won't return "false". It works fine when the value is True (prints "X") , otherwise I get an #Error .

I'm calling the function from a textbox :

```
= IIF(Code.CodeExist(Variables!MyCode.Value) = true, "X", "")


    function CodeExist( ByVal  Codigo As String) as Boolean

    dim i as integer
    dim Centinela as integer

    i = 0

    Centinela = 0 

    for i = 0  To   Report.Parameters!CodeList.Count()
         if  Report.Parameters!CodeList.Value(i) = Codigo Then
               Centinela = 1
               Exit For
         End If
    Next 


    If Centinela = 1 Then
        Return true
    Else
        Return false      // IT NEVERS RETURN FALSE even if Centinela = 0
    End If

    End function
```

I don't know what's happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

VBA has no "Return" statement. To return a value you'd use (eg)

```
....

  If Centinela = 1 Then     
   CodeExist = True 
  Else     
   CodeExist = False    
  End If  

End Function
```

or (much tidier):

```
  ....
  CodeExist = (Centinela = 1)

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very Much Tim !!!  I changed my code but I still have the same problem.  It is fine when   CodeExist = True , it prints X. But I get an #Error if the condition if false :-( , I don't know why.

Comment: @Mr Knot - then it's posssible there's some other error in your code. Try calling it from a Sub instead of the textbox and see if that allows you to catch the error.  Or put some error handling in the function and return an error message as the output.  Sorry -don't know much about SSRS - only VBA...